# Javascript - Defining a Object with Array Properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I'm not sure how to explain my question. I guess that is why I am not getting good Google search results. Anyway, I would like to create an object with a property that is an array.  I tried "this.wrong = null;" as well, and got "undefined" when I ran in the console.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

```
function Questions(question, answer, wrong) {
this.question = question;
this.answer = answer;
this.wrong = [];
};

var Question5 = new Questions("What is 1+6?", "7", ["4", "45"]);
```

my console:

```
4: Questions
   answer: "2"
   question: "What is 1+6?"
   wrong: Array[0]
   __proto__: Questionslength: 5
```

(edited to add: I am making a quiz app and am trying to store the wrong answer choices.)

Comment: Why do you need to store wrong answers? Wouldn't comparing to the correct answer be enough?

Comment: I'm making a quiz app and i wanted to store something for the 2 wrong answers. Also, I still would like to know for general purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to assign the array to the `wrong` property:

```
function Questions(question, answer, wrong) {
    this.question = question;
    this.answer = answer;
    this.wrong = wrong; // <=== Change is here
};
```

Now you can create objects the way you're doing and the `wrong` property will contain the array you passed to the constructor.